# Where's my Populist badge?

Tags: support, status-bydesign, badges

On the question [Is Skyrim Kid Friendly?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/39909/3454), someone recently earned this badge:

> **Populist:** Answer outscored an accepted answer with score of more than 10 by more than 2x. This badge can be awarded multiple times

Does only the top voted answer earn this badge? I've also outscored the top voted answer.

Comment: I think Ima ask about this internally. I don't think this generally comes up all that often for us to have a prior case I can refer to.

Answer (score 5):

Thanks to Nick Craver for investigating both the code and also finding [this little tidbit from way early on](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6851/is-the-populist-badge-broken-or-have-i-misunderstood/6938#6938). Apparently there was a prior case, haha.

At any rate, it is intentional that **only the top voted answer on any individual question can earn the Populist badge**. You *could* endeavor to earn that spot for yourself, though, haha. Only 40+ more votes to go! ♪

We'll be updating the badge description to make it clearer that only the highest voted answer is eligible for this badge.